# Convert string field to JSON array or Avro Array in Nifi record

Tags: apache-nifi, avro

I am currently getting some data in csv format that has one field which is a string encoding of a JSON array like such:

```
CED7B5D9-0378-4A37-B746-D6ED7BB35593,"[{\"a\":1},{\"a\":2}]"
D000C576-112C-45BE-BA0F-5DB0E8AF409E,"[{\"a\":3}]"
```

With millions of lines per file, I'll want to use only Record-based processors. I would like to parse it with the following avro schema:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "test",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "id", "type": "string"},
    {
      "name": "json_array", 
      "type": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "type": "record",
          "name": "array_item",
          "fields": [
            {"name": "a", "type": "int"}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But attempting to parse this file with `ConvertRecord` gives the error `Cannot convert [[{"a":1},{"a":2}]] of type class java.lang.String to Object Array...`

I think I want to use and `UpdateRecord` processor to parse the string as an object array, but I'm not sure which expression language function or record path function to use. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use groovy script for example.

Comment: @daggett yeah, I ended up making a javascript processor. Effectively, I think this means python is dead as a scripting language for us